# Windows 10 - Background image

Tags: windows-10, background

I keep changing my background picture to a photo that I have, but it keeps changing back to another photo I have after about 30-45 seconds. I'm using Windows 10. I can't seem to get rid of the original background that I set.

Comment: Is the other photo part of your Lock Screen?  That may cause what you see.

Comment: How are you changing the background picture and did you do the same for the previous one?

Comment: Is the PC managed by IT through Group Policy? How did you change the the background: CPL? A tool such as IrfanView?